# spring-web Package dependency error while building my java webapp on AWS CodeBuild

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, aws-codebuild, aws-devops

I have a simple java API webapp. When i'm trying to build my webapp using CodeBuild, it's generating a "package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist" error. But in my local machine its getting build successfully and i have also tried it manually on EC2 linux instance by installing maven and then running the commands, it got successfully built.

Below is my buildspec.yml file :

[image]

My Pom.xml file :

[image]

Error screenshot :

[image]

The file is being successfully build in EC2 instance when I'm replicating all the steps manually and in local machine its also working fine on STS.

Comment: DOn't post code as images or even worse links to images. Include all the necessary information in your question as code blocks.